# Simple yet slow mongodb query

Tags: mongodb

I think I'm missing out on something - I have a collection of about 2GB, trying to find documents by a specific value (appearing as a number or string)

I have about 14K documents in the collection.

This is the query, quite basic:

```
db.e_69.find({
    "field_groups.fields_data" : 
    {
    "$elemMatch": {
        "field_id": "502",
        "value": {"$in": ["223384",223384]}
    }
}})
```

I'm using mongoDB 3.2, small AWS server with two replica sets.

I know this is not much info - but as I'm new I'm not sure what info is required and will be happy to add according to what's needed. It's just odd for me that such a query from 14K docs would take over 3 seconds.

Am I missing something?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried examining the query using [MongoDB's explain functionality](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/)? That should be the first thing to do if you have a query running slow.

Answer (score 0):

Sort by number works faster, but you have an array, so it will slow your query down, cause it has 2 types in it.

I would suggest to add a simple boolean column and during addition of new doc if doc has "223384",223384, just set this boolean column to true value.
Then your query will be simple and search fast.
I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks YCotov, but I'm not sure I understand your answer - I'm trying to read data, retrieve information according to creteria. The reason I use both as number and string is that the user has the option to use both...

Comment: That is why it will be better if you implement additional logic during doc upload, which checks whenevr your doc has those 2 values or not, if has then set boolen value to true, otherwise to false.

Comment: But it could be any other number :) 
I just want to find a document by value - it could be any value in the field...